# Azure Maps Routing Not Accurate For Duration

Tags: bing-maps, azure-maps

If I use Bing Maps Api to calculate a journey from A to B at a specific time where I know of heavy traffic on this route I get an accurate journey duration of 24 Min delay due to heavy traffic 44 Mins in total. If I use the Azure Maps Routing Api
    https://atlas.microsoft.com/route/directions  with

```
routeType=fastest
traffic=true
travelMode=car
```

and exact same time departure date time I am not getting an traffic delay I get duration of 20.9 Mins. I understand that the data comes from Tom Tom which is different from Bing. It seems that the Azure routing is just not accurate when compared to Bing. May be I am doing something wrong?

EDIT:
Here is my example Monday 14th Jan 2019 07:30 in Azure Maps using postman:

```
 https://atlas.microsoft.com/route/directions/json?subscription-key=xxx&api-version=1.0&query=50.795225,-1.117809:50.850064,-1.071691&departAt=2019-01-14T07:30:00&travelMode=car&&traffic=true
```

Any non holiday monday is fine the route has to be in the future. This route is very traffic congested at this time 07:30.

If the put the same route into Bing maps you traveltime is

```
58 mins with 30 mins due to traffic.
```

With azure routing:

```
    "routes": [
    {
        "summary": {
            "lengthInMeters": 19357,
            "travelTimeInSeconds": 2166,
            "trafficDelayInSeconds": 0,
            "departureTime": "2019-01-14T07:30:00Z",
            "arrivalTime": "2019-01-14T08:06:05Z"
        },
```

30 mins and no delay due to traffic.

Not getting any delay due to trafiic!

Comment: Can you provide the full request with your key. What you are seeing is the opposite of what we have had reported from other customers. Generally Azure maps is more accurate.

Comment: I can't supply my key.

Comment: I meant the request without your subscription key in it. Sorry about that.

Comment: No worries have put some route info in the updated question. You should be able to cut and paste into postman but will need a key of course.

Comment: Great. Will pass this on to the data and services team for investigation.

Answer (score 1):

TomTom result does not explicitly show delays. Delays resulting from historic travel information are however included in travel time. As comparison from of Bing and TomTom routes (Start: 50.795225,-1.117809 ,Destination: 50.850064,-1.071691 , Departure: Jan 14 2019, 07:30). Results:

Bing; 
Route length; 21 km 
Travel time: 41 min 
Delay: 11 min

Azure Maps/TomTom: 
Route length; 19,35 km 
Travel time: 36 min 
Delay: 0 min

To get delay resulting from historic traffic information, routing parameter "&computeTravelTimeFor=all" needs to be added. This will not directly return delay from historic traffic, but travel times without any delays, travel time including delays from historic traffic info, travel time including delays from historic plus live traffic info